# how to play multiful audio files in a single page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Good day all, I can play a audio file now with different pages according to what @Bas H, answered my question for a couple of days and make a small project in respect of it, but now I want him or someone to show me how to play multiple audio files in a single page.

This is an example:

xaml page:

```
<Frame>
<StackLayout>
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPlay"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="Play.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" />
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPause"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="pause.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" 
            IsVisible="false"/>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="Loop:"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Switch
            x:Name="switchLoop"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            IsToggled="False"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

```
<Frame>
<StackLayout>
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPlaytwo"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="Play.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" />
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPausetwo"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="pause.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" 
            IsVisible="false"/>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="Loop:"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Switch
            x:Name="switchLooptwo"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            IsToggled="False"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

```
<Frame>
<StackLayout>
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPlaythree"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="Play.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" />
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPausethree"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="pause.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" 
            IsVisible="false"/>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="Loop:"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Switch
            x:Name="switchLoopthree"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            IsToggled="False"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

code behind:

```
 public HeadProjectAudioPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnPause.IsVisible = false;

        var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
      
        player.PlaybackEnded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            btnPlay.IsVisible = true;
            btnPause.IsVisible = false;
        };
        player.Load("running.mp3");

        btnPlay.Clicked += BtnPlayClicked;
        btnPause.Clicked += BtnPauseClicked;
        switchLoop.Toggled += SwitchLoopToggled;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        btnPause.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void SwitchLoopToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Loop = switchLoop.IsToggled;
    }

    private void BtnPlayClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPause.IsVisible = true;
        btnPlay.IsVisible = false;
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Play();       
    }

    private void BtnPauseClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPlay.IsVisible = true;
        btnPause.IsVisible = false;
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Pause();
    }

}
```

Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: each set of controls should have its own set of event handlers that will control the appropriate mp3 file.  This would be the easiest approach, although there are ways you can use the same event handler for multiple controls

Comment: and, I'd consider using just one set of controls for playback with a Picker that allows you to select which file to play

Comment: I have tried to use each set of event handlers to control the appropriate mp3 file but it's not done, that is why I raised a question on it.

Comment: please post the code you have tried and explain what problems you are having with it

Comment: Look at the above code and make your own contribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still used the picker or else the loop did not work.

Because the mp3 is loaded at startup i use a picker to change the mp3 .picker is hidden. Want to change or add a mp3 ad it to the picker.

HeadProjectAudioPage.xaml

```
 <Picker
            x:Name="picker"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            SelectedIndexChanged="picker_SelectedIndexChanged"
            IsVisible="false">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>running.mp3</x:String>
                    <x:String>Drup.mp3</x:String>
                    <x:String>Diminished.mp3</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
```

Ad this after InitializeComponent(); in HeadProjectAudioPage.xaml.cs

```
   picker.SelectedItem = "running.mp3"; ///////// You must selected before start if not a error
```

Add the 2 ImageButtons in HeadProjectAudioPage.xaml.cs

```
   btnPlaytwo.Clicked += BtnPlaytwoClicked;
        btnPlaythree.Clicked += BtnPlaythreeClicked;
```

And to start the mp3's in HeadProjectAudioPage.xaml.cs

```
private void BtnPlayClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
          picker.SelectedItem = "running.mp3";
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Play();
    }
    private void BtnPlaytwoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
          picker.SelectedItem = "Drup.mp3";
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Play();
    }

    private void BtnPlaythreeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         picker.SelectedItem = "Diminished.mp3";
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Play();
    }
```

When start a mp3 the pickers change and play that mp3 , the loop works also.
You can add the code for all the loops .

Maybe not the best way but it works , the loading of the mp3 can be on different ways. But this is an idea

Comment: Thank You for your effort. but this is not the way I want it. My Page consist with different Frames, and each frame has its own audio file to play. Look at my above page again I edited it to 3 frames. Thank you Bas H

Comment: I update the answer , the picker part is a bit dirty code but you can figure out an other way . But it works .

Comment: Thank you so much, it's ok now, I really appreciate.